# Show text file contents on it's icon

Tags: unity, 18.04

I have Ubuntu 18.04 with Unity desktop environment.
Is there a way to display text file contents on it's icon on the desktop?

Comment: I think not - how would it display my 6848 line text file? Scroll?

Comment: @waltinator it would display just as much as it fits.
And also such feature was present in old Ubuntu versions with GNOME DE.